# Understanding JVM metrics for a spark streaming job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm

I am looking into the jvm metrics emitted from all the executors for a spark streaming job.
I wanted to understand the terms usage and used assigned to each metric.
for eg:

I get metrics like-

Heap Used,
Heap Usage

What is the difference in them?